# ¿Como puedo guardar un id y cargarlo en otra pagina php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy trabanjando en una de galleria de imagenes en html-phpn donde los usuarios pueden subir imagenes y tengo un trozo de codigo que selecciona de 2 tablas la informacion de la imagen y del usuario que la publico para luego mostrar esos datos con un bucle.

```
        <div class="main-content">
    <?php

    $conn =mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','photogall');
    $select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Img.id, Img.route, Img.Name, Img.user_id, Img.Category,Img.Place,
    Usr.Nombre, Usr.Apellido
    FROM `image` Img
    INNER JOIN users Usr ON Img.user_id = Usr.id 
    ORDER BY RAND()");
    while ($filas=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
        $_SESSION['img_id'] = $filas["id"];
        ?>
    <div class="colum-content">
        <a href="../html/infofoto.php" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $filas["route"]?>" alt="Foto"></a>
        <div class="info"><?php echo $filas["Name"]?><a  href=""><?php echo $filas["Nombre"]?> <?php echo $filas["Apellido"]?></a></div>
    </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

Lo que busco hacer es guardar el id de la imagen mostrada para que al entrar al link que contiene la imagen me diriga a otra pagina y que lea el id de la imagen para cargar de la base de datos toda la informacion de dicha imagen.

Intente hacerlo con una variable de session, pero solamente me almacena el id de la primera imagen que se carga en el bucle y quiero que guarde el id de cada una de las imagenes, Tambien creando otra variable guardar el id en ella pero no encontre la forma de leerla en otra pagina.

Aguna recomendación u forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Si quieres guardar cada una en la variable de sesión debes cambiar esto:  `$_SESSION['img_id'] = $filas["id"];` por esto: **`$_SESSION[]['img_id'] = $filas["id"];`**, al colocar `[]` le indicas que vaya guardando cada `img_id` en un sub-array dentro de la variable de sesión.

Comment: Lo hice y el resultado fue una llista de este warning: Warning: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 0 in Unknown on line 0. por cada imagen